# Erro ao iniciar aplicação utilizando ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend

Comecei a estudar o *Zendframework* e Configurei conforme recomendado. Ao chamar o projeto que criei com o código padrão, funciona perfeitamente. Quando comento todo o `index.php` e adiciono o código:

```
include 'Zend.php';

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Front');

Zend_Controller_Front::run('controllers');
```

Mostra o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\ProjetoZend\public\index.php on line 5

Comment: Você tem que chamar o autoloader:  require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o autoloader do Zend (Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php):

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

CUIDADO, um detalhe pode trazer problemas, o linux é case sensitive quanto aos arquivos. Isto significa que, no linux isto

```
include ('Zend/Loader/autoloader.php');
```

é diferente disto

```
include ('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
```

Comment: Deu certo @lai0n com a sua dica!